# How to read xml file in .net windows application in different directory?

Tags: .net, xml, winforms

I have one .net windows application I'm trying to read .xml file from c# windows application.

but i'm getting error :

> Could not find a part of the path 'c:\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\bin\Debug\~\Files\test.xml'.

but my file is in `Files` folder which is in application `WindowsFormsApplication1` only
not in  `\bin\Debug`

then why it is searching into `\bin\Debug` ?

code in form.cs

```
DataSet dsAuthors = new DataSet("authors");
            string filePath = @"~/Files/test.xml";

            dsAuthors.ReadXml(filePath);
```

also please tell me is there any way to use Server.MapPath like we do it in web application.

I tried other solution like :

```
string appPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);

            System.IO.DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = System.IO.Directory.GetParent(appPath);
            System.IO.DirectoryInfo directoryInfo2 = System.IO.Directory.GetParent(directoryInfo.FullName);

            string path = directoryInfo2.FullName + @"\Files";
```

but getting error :
`Access to the path is denied.`

Comment: \bin\Debug is the default path when you start your application in Debug mode. Set the starting path in your project properties.

Comment: you can change the settings of test.xml - file in your solution to be copied into the debug-folder as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
        string filePath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, Path.Combine("Files", "test.xml"));// @"~/Files/test.xml";
```

If it doesn't work make sure that the test.xml has "Copy to output directory" property set to "Copy always".

Answer (score 0):

Use `Server.MapPath`

You are using a relative url. This will not work with ReadXml. It needs the absolute path on your disk.

Server.MapPath will take your virtual path and give you its absolute path.

```
var fullPath = Server.MapPath("~/Files/test.xml");
dsAuthors.ReadXml(fullPath);
```

Note: Server.MapPath doesn't verify if the path actually exists.

Comment: server.mappath is not available in WinForms apps

Comment: The concept of a ~ in the path doesn't exist in winforms

Comment: server.mappath is not available in WinForms apps - any other alternative for this?

Comment: Don't use a ~ . Your exe will always run in your output folder. Specify your path from there. A better approach would be to copy this test.xml to output. Assuming directory structures that you are not creating is asking for trouble.